# Traverse a binary tree using dfs, stopping at a given point (in Python)

Tags: python, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I'm learning about some basic computer science concepts. As a demo, I'm creating a script in Python that will perform various functions on a binary tree. I've been able to successfully program most of these functions, except for one specific one.

For a binary tree created from an array of integers, I would like to do a depth first search for an integer, and return the path that was taken through the tree up until that integer was found as an array (with the last number in that array being the number that was being searched for). As soon as the first match for that integer is found, I want to stop traversing the tree.

For example, for an inorder dfs of array [3,2,4,1,4,6,8,5] for integer 4, it should return [1,2,3,4]

For integer 5 it should return [1,2,3,4,4,5] etc.

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value=value
        self.left=None
        self.right=None

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

def buildTree(array):
    print("building tree....")
    root=Node(array[0])
    del(array[0])
    for a in array:
        insert(root,Node(a))
    print("building complete")
    return root

def insert(root,node): 
    if root is None: 
        root = node 
    else: 
        if root.value < node.value: 
            if root.right is None: 
                root.right = node 
            else: 
                insert(root.right, node) 
        else: 
            if root.left is None: 
                root.left = node 
            else: 
                insert(root.left, node) 

def depthFirstSearch(root,target,results,subSearch):
#0:preorder
#1:inorder
#2:postorder
    if root!=None:

        if subSearch==0:
            results.append(root.getValue())
            if root.getValue()==target:
                return results

        depthFirstSearch(root.left,target,results,subSearch)

        if subSearch==1:
            results.append(root.getValue())
            if root.getValue()==target:
                return results

        depthFirstSearch(root.right,target,results,subSearch)

        if subSearch==2:
            results.append(root.getValue())
            if root.getValue()==target:
                return results

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #stuff that gets our arguments
    #...
    array=[3,2,4,1,4,6,8,5] #we would actually get this as an argument, but using this for example array
    target=4 #example target
    subSearch=1 #using inorder traversal for this example

    root=buildTree(array)
    results=[]
    results=depthFirstSearch(root,target,results,subSearch) 
    print(results) #expected:[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: I tried various solutions, besides simply "return results" upon finding the target, however I was unable to find one that worked. So, I used that for sake of simplicity.

Comment: Also, I do not want to traverse the entire tree and simply only print the array up until the target. I want to actually terminate the search!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The variables you use are not defined (`array`, `target`,`subSearch`).

Comment: It looks like you are confusing an `array` with a binary tree. Your `depthFirstSearch()` function is expecting a `root` that is supposedly an instance of the class `Node`. But in your call to `depthFirstSearch` you are passing the first element of an array of integers to it instead. You have `depthFirstSearch(array[0], ...)`. The first thing you'll need to do is to convert your array to a binary tree consisting of `Node`s.

Comment: It's because I screwed up when I was making this post. I added the functions used to build the tree.

Comment: @ZEE Now it makes a lot of sense, quick question, if it reaches a leaf node and still hasn't found the node, then should that leaf be in the results, i.e. the path would be from top, or all the blocks travelled before reaching that point?

Comment: @anand_v.singh I'm not so sure the DFS implementation is correct. The condition `if root.getValue()==target: return results` does not guarantee that the search immediately stops after target is found because of the placement of this if inside a recursive call. There is no back-propagation of the information that the search needs to immediately halt. This is why if you run his code as-is, it returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4]`. Note that it finds the target `4`, but continues searching.

Comment: @darksky Oh, didn't consider that, added answer to implement that functionality. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is easy, just use an Additional variable flag and then your function becomes

```
def depthFirstSearch(root,target,results,subSearch, flag = 0):
#0:preorder
#1:inorder
#2:postorder
    if root!=None:

        if subSearch==0:
            results.append(root.getValue())
            if root.getValue()==target:
                return results, 1

        results, flag =depthFirstSearch(root.left,target,results,subSearch)
        if flag == 1:
            return results, flag
        if subSearch==1:
            results.append(root.getValue())
            if root.getValue()==target:
                return results, 1

        results, flag = depthFirstSearch(root.right,target,results,subSearch)
        if flag == 1:
            return results, flag

        if subSearch==2:
            results.append(root.getValue())
            if root.getValue()==target:
                return results, 1

    return results, flag
```

Here Flag changes to one and that is propagated as the function stack shrinks, keeping them after each recursive calls takes care of this.

Also in main function, the function call becomes

```
results, _=depthFirstSearch(root,target,results,subSearch)
```

Since `flag = 0` is present in function definition you just need to discard the second variable, you can even use that to check if the element was found in the tree rather than just printing the whole tree if element is not present.

If you have any doubts or concerns, comment below.